# pytest and python testing: Report test cases written for a python function

Tags: python, pytest

I want to generate a report for test cases written for a python function in pytest. Are there any pytest parameters which can be used or anyway we can parse the reports to accomplish this?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps use the `--junitxml` arg to create an XML report `py.test my_tests.py --junitxml=/path/to/report.xml`

Comment: Docs for pytest's JUnitXml export are [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/usage.html#creating-junitxml-format-files)

Comment: And [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-reportlog) is a pytest plugin for generating a relatively simple JSON report.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, This helps in getting the functions which are being used for testing, but I can't find out which functions are getting tested by these tests. 

Is there a way to get that done?